# How to set user "logon to" AD attribute in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I'm working on upgrading a solution in VB.NET that is heavily based on Active Directory.  As of now, I'm trying to add a PC restriction to a new AD User upon user creation.  Essentially, I need to update the Logon To attribute to include 1 or more PCs, how do I go about doing this?

I learned that I am interested in the IADsUser property "`LoginWorkstations`" (thanks to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa746340).  As of now, I have code that can fetch this attribute from any AD user, but I cannot set it.

Here is the code I have to fetch the attribute:

```
Dim userADObject As new DirectoryEntry(ADPath)
Dim logonToPC as String = userADObject.InvokeGet("LoginWorkstations")(0).ToString
```

That will fetch the first restricted PC (if there is one) and save it in `logonToPC` and will look something like "`PC10000`"

That works great, so intuitively I would assume something like this would work:

```
Dim userADObject As new DirectoryEntry(ADPath)
Dim args() As Object = {"PC100001"}
userADObject.InvokeSet("LoginWorkstations", args)
```

But it doesn't work... It just throws a rather unhelpful exception.

I've tried testing this approach with a different attribute and it works just fine.  Not much out there on Google either unfortunately...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution that works.  I took marc_s's code and modified a bit to work properly.  here's what I have:

```
Dim userADObject As New DirectoryEntry(Me.ADPath)
'Grab the previous restriction, because we may have to clear it first in the future
Dim priorRestriction As String = userADObject.Properties("userWorkstations").Value

If priorRestriction = "" Then
     'Simply add
     userADObject.Properties("userWorkstations").Add("PC001,PC002")
Else
     'Important - We have to clear the old restriction before adding the new
     userADObject.Properties("userWorkstations").Remove(priorRestriction)
     'Now add the new restriction
     userADObject.Properties("userWorkstations").Add(priorRestriction & ",PC003")
End If
'Commit!
userADObject.CommitChanges()
```

Something that gave me some pretty good grief what that I you can't have a space in the string being added.  Example: `.Add("PC001, PC002")` **has to be** `.Add("PC001,PC002")`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this fairly easily - also: note that you should use the `userWorkstations` LDAP attribute ([see note here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) - this is multi-valued, e.g. it allows multiple entries.

```
Dim userADObject As new DirectoryEntry(ADPath)

userADObject.Properties("userWorkstations").Add("PC001")
userADObject.Properties("userWorkstations").Add("PC002")
userADObject.Properties("userWorkstations").Add("PC003")

userADObject.CommitChanges()
```

If you have the necessary permissions to update Active Directory, that should basically do it, I think.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I can successfully add the first PC (if the user doesn't already have a restriction), but as soon as I try to add and commit the second or third PC, I get "The specified directory service attribute or value already exists." I obviously verified in AD that the user doesn't actually already have these PC assignments.  Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out marc_s.  Check out my answer.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!